# LINQ where clause, filter on boolean(grandchild) inside array(child) that's inside array(parent)

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

If this is a duplicate please let me know, I searched everywhere.. This may just be a simple LINQ concept that I am not familiar with.

---

This is a simplified version of my data structure:

```
public interface ICourse
{
  List<ISession> Sessions { get; set; }
}

public interface ISession
{
  Boolean InRange { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem:** I have a `List<ICourse>`. I want to return all courses (`ICourse`), but filter the sessions (`ISession`) on those courses and only include sessions that are `InRange` (`true`).

**Tried:**

```
List<ICourse> results = //data retrieval.
return results.Where(course => course.Sessions
              .Where(session => session.InRange).ToList<ISession>())
              .ToList<ICourse>();
```

**Errors:**
*Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<ISession>'` to `'bool'`.*

*Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.*

Obviously it does not complain when I only use one `Where` clause, i.e.:

```
return results.Where(course => course.Sessions.Count > 0).ToList<ICourse>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
results
  .Where(course => 
    course.Sessions.Where(session => session.InRange).ToList<ISession>()
  )
  .ToList<ICourse>();
```

`Where()` is a filter. It needs a lambda that returns `bool`. `Where` gives your lambda each item in the enumeration in turn, and the lambda is expected to answer a yes-or-no question: "Do you want to include this thing in the results?"

Here's the answer you're trying to give to that question:

```
  course.Sessions.Where(session => session.InRange).ToList<ISession>()
```

That returns a list of `ISession`. `Where` asks your lambda, "Do you want this thing?" and instead of "yes" or "no", your lambda says, "Hey, look at all these sessions!" In C#, that's not a yes-or-no answer.

The compiler sees this comedy routine coming a mile away, and pulls the plug before anything silly happens at runtime.

So.

If you want to return a list of `ICourse`, but you want them to have only a subset of the sessions they start with, you can't do that without creating new course objects. Since what you've got here are interfaces, let's not try to create new objects. I doubt you'd want to in any case.

You can get a flat list of all sessions that are `InRange`:

```
results.SelectMany(c => c.Sessions.Where(s => s.InRange)).ToList();
```

And you can get a list of tuples or an anonymous type which pair a reference to an `ICourse` with a list of in-range sessions belonging to that course:

```
results.Select(c => 
    new Tuple<ICourse, List<ISession>>(
        c, 
        c.Sessions.Where(session => session.InRange).ToList()
    ))
.ToList();
```

And you can filter that to exclude any courses that have no in-range sessions:

```
results.Select(c => 
    new Tuple<ICourse, List<ISession>>(
        c, 
        c.Sessions.Where(session => session.InRange).ToList()
    ))
.Where(t => t.Item2.Any())
.ToList();
```

If this isn't just an ad-hoc thing off in some little corner of your application, I'd urge you to write a custom class to replace that `Tuple`.

Or in C#7:

```
public List<(ICourse Course, List<ISession> Sessions)> 
    GetInRangeSessions(IEnumerable<ICourse> courses) 
    =>
        courses
        .Select(c =>
            (Course: c, Sessions: c.Sessions.Where(session => session.InRange).ToList())
        )
        .ToList();
```

Just a few more irritating superfluous parentheses in this language, and we'll be mining the asteroids.

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete, wonderful answer. With your help, I was able to make my code work (nice) and expand my understanding of LINQ (even nicer).

Answer (score 2):

Ed Plunkett's answer is correct, but I must ask, why do you want a new `ICourse` objects list.  Why not just use the full ICourse list, and just filter the Sessions where they are being used:

```
 foreach(var c in Courses)
 {
      foreach(var s in c.Sessions.Where(session => session.InRange))
      {.... }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest idea is just to write:

```
List<Sessions> temporary = new List<Sessions>();

        foreach (Course s in courses)
        {
            temporary = s.sessions.Where(x => x.InRange == true).ToList();
            s.sessions = temporary;
            temporary.Clear();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all Course Where a Session is InRange, I would try... (Not tested)

```
List<ICourse> results = //data retrieval.
return results.Where(course => course.Sessions.Where(session => session.InRange)).ToList<ISession>()).ToList<ICourse>();
```

Comment: You have unbalanced brackets making it hard to judge exactly what you are trying to do here (you have four opening `(` and five closing `)`). Even aside from that I am not convinced that anywhere you put the brackets will allow you to return courses with in place filtering of the sessions on those courses...

Comment: This fails to compile with the same error OP gets. It's fine to submit an "agile" answer that you haven't tested yet, but then you go back and test it.